# Windows services: force windows to attempt to start service after failed attempts

Tags: windows, services

Appears that after a Windows service fails to start once or twice (with the ~"Service failed to respond in a timely fashion" error) then Windows ceases even trying to start the service and just instantly errors.

Is there a way to force Windows to actually try running the service **without restarting**?

Comment: Have you tried the options on the Recovery tab? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753662.aspx

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue by any chance? I am seeing same problem where service on failure would be restarted, but it then gives up if it fails during the startup time.